# Django: When print a QuerySet gives an error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-queryset

I have a table(SavedSchedules) below in the database. `hall_n_time` and `schedule` columns stores two python lists as string.

```
+----+---------------+-------------+----------+
| id |   lecturer    | hall_n_time | schedule |
+----+---------------+-------------+----------+
|... |      ...      |     ...     |    ...   |
+----+---------------+-------------+----------+
```

I have below script in `views.py`:

```
lec_name = User.objects.filter(username=request.session['logged_username']).values_list('lecturer_name', flat=True)
print(lec_name)
```

This gives OUTPUT:

```
<QuerySet ['A. B. C. Watson']>
```

But EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
A. B. C. Watson
```

Then I tried below script:

```
lec_name = User.objects.filter(username=request.session['logged_username']).values_list('lecturer_name', flat=True)
schedule_data = SavedSchedules.objects.filter(lecturer=lec_name)
print(schedule_data)
```

It gives below ERROR when I execute it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BhathiyaTK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\BhathiyaTK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\BhathiyaTK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Web Projects\CIS_ALTG\altg\altg_app\views.py", line 497, in profile
    print(schedule_data)
  File "C:\Users\BhathiyaTK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 252, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "C:\Users\BhathiyaTK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 276, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\BhathiyaTK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\BhathiyaTK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\BhathiyaTK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1124, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "C:\Users\BhathiyaTK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 498, in as_sql
    where, w_params = self.compile(self.where) if self.where is not None else ("", [])
  File "C:\Users\BhathiyaTK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 415, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\BhathiyaTK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\where.py", line 81, in as_sql
    sql, params = compiler.compile(child)
  File "C:\Users\BhathiyaTK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 415, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\BhathiyaTK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 177, in as_sql
    rhs_sql, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
  File "C:\Users\BhathiyaTK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 270, in process_rhs
    'The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to '
ValueError: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.
[30/Apr/2020 17:26:37] "GET /profile/ HTTP/1.1" 500 122259
```

I'm new to Django and I have no idea why it gives this kind of error. Can someone explain why this happens and how to solve these issues? I appreciate your help. I'm using Python 3.7.4, Django 3.0.1

Comment: This is all described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to get the list of``SavedSchedules` objects for the currently logged in user?

Comment: Yes. @MihaiChelaru

Comment: Please show your models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `values_list` will still give you a queryset, but it has a list inside. you can get the values as a pure list using:

```
lec_name = list(User.objects.filter(username=request.session['logged_username']).values_list('lecturer_name', flat=True))[0]
print(lec_name)
```

This gets the first element in the list, which should be your lecturer name.

The issue with

```
schedule_data = SavedSchedules.objects.filter(lecturer=lec_name)
print(schedule_data)
```

is that in your current form, `lec_name` is a queryset/list, and SavedSchedules can't look for objects where its lecturer = a list. Either use my modification above to get a single lecturer, or use this syntax to get SavedSchedules where the lecturer is from a list:

```
schedule_data = SavedSchedules.objects.filter(lecturer__in=lec_list)
```

Hope those suggestions help, happy coding!